# equivalent of pipefail in GNU make?

Tags: makefile, pipe

Say I have the following files:

buggy_program:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "wops, some bug made me exit with failure"
exit 1
```

Makefile:

```
file.gz:
    buggy_program | gzip -9 -c >$@
```

Now if I type `make`, GNU make will happily build `file.gz` even though `buggy_program` exited with non-zero status.

In bash I could do `set -o pipefail` to make a pipeline exit with failure if at least one program in the pipeline exits with failure. Is there a similar method in GNU make? Or some workaround that doesn't involve temporary files? (The reason for gzipping here is precisely to avoid a huge temporary file.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a possible solution that doesn't require bash. Imagine you have two programs `thisworks` and `thisfails` that fail or work fine, respectively. Then the following will only leave you with `work.gz`, deleting `fail.gz`, ie. create the gzipped make target if and only if the program executed correctly:

```
all: fail.gz work.gz

work.gz:
    ( thisworks && touch $@.ok ) | gzip -c -9 >$@
    rm $@.ok || rm $@

fail.gz:
    ( thisfails && touch $@.ok ) | gzip -c -9 >$@
    rm $@.ok || rm $@
```

Explanation:

In the first line of the `work.gz` rule, `thisworks` will exit with success, and a file `work.gz.ok` will be created, and all stdout goes through gzip into `work.gz`. Then in the second line, because `work.gz.ok` exists, the first `rm` command also exits with success – and since `||` is [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), the second `rm` *does not get run* and so `work.gz` is not deleted.

OTOH, in the first line of the `fail.gz` rule, `thisfails` will exit with failure, and `fail.gz.ok` will *not* be created. All stdout still goes through gzip into `fail.gz`. Then in the second line, because `fail.gz.ok` does *not* exist, the first `rm` command exits with failure, so `||` tries the second `rm` command which deletes the `fail.gz` file.

---

To easily check that this works as it should, simply replace `thisworks` and `thisfails` with the commands `true` and `false`, respectively, put it in a Makefile and type `make`.

(Thanks to the kind people in #autotools for helping me with this.)

Comment: Could you explain this answer a little bit? I'm not sure I quite understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 45):

Try this

```
SHELL=/bin/bash -o pipefail

file.gz:
    buggy_program | gzip -9 -c >$@
```

Comment: Note that this will affect every rule in the file. Even those above.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with `/usr/bin/env`?

Comment: Doesn't work. Make interprets it as a single command.

Answer (score 11):

You could do:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
file.gz:
    set -o pipefail; buggy_program | gzip -9 -c >$@
```

but this **only work with bash**.

Comment: I prefer this solution, because it doesn't change the behaviour of the whole file.