# How to set pipefail in a Makefile

Tags: error-handling, makefile, pipe

Consider this Makfile:

```
all: 
    test 1 -eq 2 | cat
    echo 'done'
```

It will be executed with no error.

I've heard of `set -o pipefail` that I may use like this:

```
all: 
    set -o pipefail;     \
    test 1 -eq 2 | cat;  \
    echo 'done'
```

Apart that it does not work, this writing is very painful.

Another solution would be to use temporary files. I would like to avoid it.

What other solution can I use?

Comment: How does that second snippet not work? It should work just fine (other than `cat` being pointless there obviously). Or did you mean that it doesn't prevent `done` from being echoed out? It doesn't do that because nothing tells the shell to stop executing. You only have a single line here not multiples so make can't terminate for the `test` failure (even though it propagates past the `| cat`). Drop the `; \` between `cat` and `echo` and it'll do what you expect.

Comment: I don't get any errors with my `GNU Make 4.1`

Comment: With your example code you **shouldn't** get any errors. The `test` failure just gets ignored. Nothing looks at it. You are expecting make to see it and fail the recipe but that only happens for the return code of the *entire* command (normally a single line but in your case the concatenated set of three lines).

Comment: In my use case I am using a home made cksum script that I pipe into `dd -of=$@ -seek=$$(( $$(stat -c %s $@) - 4 ))`. If the cksum fail, dd should also fail and I should never execute the rest of the commands.

Comment: Then if you want to use a continued line in a makefile you need to check for failure and exit yourself because make won't do that for you. `set -o pipefail; \ cksum ... | dd || exit 1; \ echo done`

Comment: Or use two lines `set -o pipefail; \ cksum ... | dd ... || exit 1` and `echo done` *without* merging those together.

Comment: Thanks, I've just realized it while reading your previous comment. However the syntax is very annoying. I am looking for a more definitive solution where i tell make to always enable `set -o pipefail` for all pipes.

Comment: You enable it *for a given shell session*. So you need to make sure you do that for *each* session you have. Each line is a new session. If you don't want that you can use `.ONESHELL` in make 4.1 (but realize that will prevent make from **ever** bailing a recipe out for a recipe-internal non-zero return code so you get to check your commands yourself at all times.\

Comment: And this isn't a syntax problem this is a semantics issue. You don't fully grasp how make works here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96190/discussion-between-nowox-and-etan-reisner).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anything more complicated than single commands I generally prefer using a script. That way you control the interpreter completely (via the [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376206/96588)), and you can put more complicated commands together rather than trying to shoe-horn it into effectively a single line. For example:

`Makefile`:

```
all:
    ./my.sh
```

`my.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit -o pipefail
test 1 -eq 2 | cat
echo 'done'
```

That said, **the exit code of a Makefile command block like the one you have is the exit code of the *last* command since you separate the commands with `;`.** You can use `&&` to execute only until you get an error (equivalent to `errexit`), like this:

```
set -o pipefail && test 1 -eq 2 | cat && echo 'done'
```

Comment: This could be a solution, but then you will have dozens of scripts related to your Makefile. Then, I am wondering how do you organize it.

Comment: Like any other complex project, you'll want to make that complexity manageable. And a lot of scripts doing one thing each is generally a lot more manageable than a single huge makefile.

Comment: Do you know good *GitHub* projects that I can take inspiration from?

Comment: I've got a few [makefile includes](https://github.com/l0b0/make-includes) which I use in various other projects, but I'd just try to keep it as simple as possible. And make sure you use a real language rather than shell at every possible opportunity. The code may be longer, but you'll save yourself so much grief in terms of maintainability and testability.

Comment: That's my very problem. Today I rewrote a script written in Perl that split files by adding checksum at the end of each one for a shell script embedded into the target. I gave a try in Python, but it is too slow to work with (about 5-10 times slower than Perl which is sometime slower than pure shell script.

Comment: You might want to ask about that script on [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It shouldn't be any appreciably slower in any major language than any other, and certainly not in Python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96188/discussion-between-nowox-and-l0b0).

Answer (score 18):

You can force pipefail on as part of make's SHELL invocation
From [equivalent of pipefail in GNU make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079651/equivalent-of-pipefail-in-gnu-make)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash -o pipefail
```

Comment: Thanks. This should probably be the accepted answer here. Short, concise and solves it generally for all shell invocations in the `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the SHELL variable in a Makefile works, however Make normally uses `/bin/sh` as shell, so minor differences creep in.

I grew fond of adding colors to the makeoutput, but these now come out wrong when changing from sh to bash shell.

Here is a makefile

```
SHELL=/bin/bash #-o pipefail 

LYELLOW ="\\033[1;33m"
NC      ="\\033[0m"

demo1:
    @ set +o pipefail && echo $(LYELLOW)"I will fail"$(NC) && test 1 -eq 2 | cat
    @ echo done
    
demo2:
    @ set -o pipefail && echo $(LYELLOW)"I will fail"$(NC) && test 1 -eq 2 | cat
    @ echo done

demo3:
    @ set -o pipefail && echo -e $(LYELLOW)"I will fail"$(NC) && test 1 -eq 2 | cat
    @ echo done
```

That by running demo1 and demo2 produces the output:

```
$ make demo1
\033[1;33mI will fail\033[0m
done

$make demo2
\033[1;33mI will fail\033[0m
make: *** [Makefile:11: demo2] Error 1
```

that is all very well with using the (outcommented in the Makefile above) global pipefail ala `SHELL=/bin/bash -o pipefail` or just by adding perline pipefails ala

`set -o pipefail && "some commands>"`

But colors are now output correctly anymore (the backslashes now comes out directly to the terminal, colors also being hard to show here, anyway).

The fix for this it to add an `-e` on the echo statements using the `bash` shell as in the `demo3` target, somehow not needed when running `sh`.